# No module named 'simplekml'

Tags: python, kml

I have tried to run a code that was working normally a few days ago and today it shows that error as can been below.

Now I tried to install `simplekml` from the terminal, it showed that's already installed and when I run the code again it gives the same error. Do you have any idea what might be wrong and how to fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/alkon/PycharmProjects/KML routes generated by python/kmlroutescript.py", line 2, in <module>
    import simplekml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplekml'
```

Comment: Do you have 2 python interpreters. Check ```python --version``` in the terminal. The version showed is the interpreter for which ```simplekml``` is installed

Comment: check if pycharm is using the main interpreter and not a venv, try running the file from terminal, do you still get the error?

Comment: Hello, it shows that I have python 3.8.3, How can I check if python is using the main interpreter? and how can I run the file from the terminal ? sorry for all these questions but I am still new to python

Answer (score 1):

You installed `simplekml` from your terminal, but most probably that interpreter is not used by your PyCharm.

Navigate to `Preferences > Project > Python Interpreter`. You will see your installed libraries there. There is an `add` button to add a new library.

You can also write:

```
import simplekml
```

In a python file and use PyCharm’s line pop-up suggestions to download the library.

---

Suggestions: Use one interpreter to avoid such confusions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install in a new virtual environment [use this reference for vitual environment](https://towardsdatascience.com/virtual-environments-for-absolute-beginners-what-is-it-and-how-to-create-one-examples-a48da8982d4b)
and then run the file in the new virtual environment.

```
install virtualenv

python -m virtualenv -h

venv\scripts\activate

pip install simplekml

python kmlroutescript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

In Google colab working, I faced this issue and solved the problem like this:

```
first install

!pip install **scikit-multilearn**
```

Then import from **skmultilearn**.

```
problem_transform import BinaryRelevance
```